# VBA resize table to fit to page's width

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to resize a table to fit to the pages width via VBA code.

I have tried it with the following code:

```
 mytable.PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
 mytable.PreferredWidth = 100
```

Can anyone tell me how I can resize the table to the page size? My first page has an edge of 2 centimeters and because of this the table jumps to page 2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is unclear: You talk about width, then say the table jumps to the next page, which is a height issue. Please explain in more detail about the table and the document set up so that the question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the AutoFitBehavior property of the table.

mytable.AutoFitBehavior = wdAutoFitWindow

[AutoFitBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.table.autofitbehavior)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! I have tried your code and now it looks like this: 

[link](https://ibb.co/2ssh8rg) (I can't find how to include images into comments)

Is it possible to resize the table up to the yellow line?

Comment: Did you remove the PreferredWidth setting before setting the AutoFitBehavior property? I don't know if they conflict with each other but it is worth trying them separately. Usually when I have Word table width issues, its because I tried to set the table width too wide and Word sort of gives up trying to format it.